# Cannot find name 'GlobalCompositeOperation' & Angular Compiler requires TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, animation

Same issue than [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71796111/cannot-find-name-globalcompositeoperation), but when I update to typescript to 4.6, I get:

> Error: The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=4.4.2 and <4.6.0 but
> 4.6.3 was found instead

It is just a matter of updating Angular? My version:

```
Angular CLI: 13.2.6
Node: 16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.3.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 13.2.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.6
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.2.6
@angular/cli                    13.2.6
@schematics/angular             13.2.6
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.6.3
```

**EDIT:**
The issues I referred first, with the typescript version 4.5.5 are the following:

```
Error: node_modules/tsparticles-engine/types/Options/Classes/BackgroundMask/BackgroundMask.d.ts:6:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GlobalCompositeOperation'.

6     composite: GlobalCompositeOperation;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/tsparticles-engine/types/Options/Interfaces/BackgroundMask/IBackgroundMask.d.ts:4:16 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GlobalCompositeOperation'.

4     composite: GlobalCompositeOperation;
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/tsparticles-engine/types/Utils/CanvasUtils.d.ts:19:201 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GlobalCompositeOperation'.

19 export declare function drawParticle(container: Container, context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, particle: IParticle, delta: IDelta, colorStyles: IParticleColorStyle,backgroundMask: boolean, composite: GlobalCompositeOperation, radius: number, opacity: number, shadow: IShadow): void;
   
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~




× Failed to compile.
```

Comment: Do you use `ngx-lottie`? If not, can you show the full error you get when using the previous version of typescript 4.5.x? You can't update to Typescript 4.6 yet, it's only going to be supported in the upcoming version of Angular 14.x (you could use the pre-release version `14.0.0-next.13`)

Comment: No I do not use it. Post edited with the errors.

Comment: The error comes from a dependency on tsparticles. I looked through the project and you should use version 1.42.4 for Angular 13.x. There's an issue here https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/issues/3853 but it got closed.

Comment: That is a great progress, but now I can not import { loadFull } from "tsparticles"; which is the approach provided https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/tree/main/components/angular

Comment: Check the documentation for version 1.42.4 here https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/tree/tsparticles%401.42.4/components/angular

Comment: After installing that tsparticles@1.42.4 I reinstalled the ng-particles to the version 2.42.4 to be compatible. Now I face another error after including the code for that 1.42.4, which is: Type '(main: Engine) => void' is not assignable to type '(engine: Engine) => Promise<void>'       for the particlesInit property

Comment: It seems like the doc for 1.42 is outdated. You should revert your particlesInit function. Try importing loadFull from `tsparticles-engine` maybe. I'm not familiar with that lib.

Comment: I think I found the import for loadFull, try: `import { loadFull } from 'tsparticles/full';`